# How to filter between dates from Pie Chart using Google API, PHP and MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-visualization

I Have created the script to generate the pie chart based on data from my database. It is displaying the work hours based on department just fine. **However, I am unable to display by filtering between dates.** Can I know what or how the code needs to be fixed to filter. In database I have already created timestamp named ***"CreatedOn".***

```
<?php   
     try {
        $query = $connection->prepare("SELECT Department, SUM(workHrs) as number FROM serviceapplication GROUP BY Department");
        $query->execute();
        $query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $data = $query->fetchAll();
    
    // var_dump($data);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
     ?> 
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    
    function drawChart() {
    
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Department', 'Work Hours'],
          <?php
              foreach($data as $data) :     
                echo "['".$data["Department"]."', ".$data["number"]."],";
              endforeach; 
              ?>
        ]);
        
        var options = {
            backgroundColor: "none",
            title: '',
            width: 900,
            height: 500,
            pieHole: 0.5,
            colors: ['#4c325c', '#8ea5cc', '#aa579f', '#391d9d', '#fcbd9c', '#dc346c'],
        };
        
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
        
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
    </script>
    

  <form action="" method="GET">
        <label class="text-secondary">From Date</label>
                <input type="date" name="from_date2" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['from_date2'])){ echo $_GET['from_date2']; } ?>" class="form-control">
 
         
          <label class="text-secondary">To Date</label>
                 <input type="date" name="to_date2" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['to_date2'])){ echo $_GET['to_date2']; } ?>" class="form-control">
                      
          <label class="text-secondary">Filter</label> <br>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Filter</button>
             
           </form>
            <br>
            <?php 
                                    if(isset($_GET['from_date2']) && isset($_GET['to_date2']))
                                    {
                                        $from_date2 = $_GET['from_date2'];
                                        $to_date2 = $_GET['to_date2'];
    
                                        try {
                                            $query = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM serviceapplication WHERE CreatedOn BETWEEN '$from_date2' AND '$to_date2' ");
                                            $query->execute();
                                            $query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                                            $data = $query->fetchAll();
                                            $count = 0;
    
                                        // var_dump($data);
                                        } catch (PDOException $e) {
                                            echo $e->getMessage();
                                        }
                                        foreach($data as $data) :                           
                                        ?>
                                             <div id="piechart"></div>
                                        <?php   
                                        endforeach;
                                        }
                                        ?>
```

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use prepared statements **and parameters** to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / PDO. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Modified Code , you need to set $data array accordingly.
2. FIlter - group by column and required fields (currently i grouped by dept)

   ```
          try {

   if (isset($_GET['from_date2']) && isset($_GET['to_date2'])) {

                                                   $from_date2 = $_GET['from_date2'];

                                                   $to_date2 = $_GET['to_date2'];


           //SQL injection you can handle                                  
           $query = $connection->prepare("SELECT Department, SUM(workHrs) as number  FROM serviceapplication WHERE CreatedOn BETWEEN ? AND ?  GROUP BY Department");

           //$query->bind_param("ss", $from_date2, $to_date2);

           $query->execute(array($from_date2, $to_date2));

                                      //$query->execute();
                                                       $query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                                                       $data = $query->fetchAll();
                                                       $count = 0;
                                                       echo "data goes here = date filter ";print_r($data); 

           } else {
                   $query = $connection->prepare("SELECT Department, SUM(workHrs) as number FROM serviceapplication GROUP BY Department");
                   $query->execute();
                   $query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                   $data = $query->fetchAll();
                   echo "data goes here";print_r($data); 
           }

           } catch (PDOException $e) {
                                                       echo $e->getMessage();
           }

           ?>



           <head>
           <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script> 
           <script type="text/javascript">
           google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
           google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

           function drawChart() {

           var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
             ['Department', 'Work Hours'],
             <?php
                 foreach($data as $data) :     
                   echo "['".$data["Department"]."', ".$data["number"]."],";
                 endforeach; 
                 ?>
           ]);

           var options = {
               backgroundColor: "none",
               title: '',
               width: 900,
               height: 500,
               pieHole: 0.5,
               colors: ['#4c325c', '#8ea5cc', '#aa579f', '#391d9d', '#fcbd9c', '#dc346c'],
           };

           var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

           chart.draw(data, options);
           }
           </script>


           <form action="" method="GET">
           <label class="text-secondary">From Date</label>
                   <input type="date" name="from_date2" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['from_date2'])){ echo $_GET['from_date2']; } ?>" class="form-control">


             <label class="text-secondary">To Date</label>
                    <input type="date" name="to_date2" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['to_date2'])){ echo $_GET['to_date2']; } ?>" class="form-control">

             <label class="text-secondary">Filter</label> <br>
                     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Filter</button>

              </form>
               <br>
           <?php
           print_r($data);

           foreach($data as $dat) :                           
                                           ?>
                                                <div id="piechart"></div>
                                           <?php   
                                           endforeach;

                                           ?>
   ```

Comment: Thanks Senthil for the modified code....can I know where to place the pie chart JavaScript and <div id="piechart"></div> from your modified code...

Comment: Put it as it is , just move the date filter logic (To Query once and show the data in your html code base) to a your upper block as shown in my code ref.

Comment: I get this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "catch"....

Comment: Refer to updated Code  in the Answer section.

Comment: I have used the updated code.....however it is not displaying the piechart if I filter between the dates......

Comment: try printing var_dump( $data) or print_r( $data) to see what data you received.

Comment: Modified code / Query fix / Refer to updated code //SQL injection you can handle                                  
$query = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM serviceapplication WHERE CreatedOn BETWEEN ? AND ?");


$query->execute(array($from_date2, $to_date2));

Comment: printing var_dump( $data) only display the last inserted data....
the updated code still not filtering between dates.....I tried with POST method but still the same ....

Comment: Root cause , for the date filter we missed group by . Revised query condition for date filter $query = $connection->prepare("SELECT Department, SUM(workHrs) as number  FROM serviceapplication WHERE CreatedOn BETWEEN ? AND ?  GROUP BY Department");